# ReactJS: handling invalid dynamic links and rendering 404 error message

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

App link: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-darwin-rq1ew?fontsize=14

Similar question asked: [How to handle 404 in Reactjs dynamic pages based on Ajax response?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58023199/8738008)

I am fetching an API call and rendering only names from data to `Shop` component. Then providing a dynamic link to those name by providing id i.e. `/shop/:itemId`.

Here I want to handle "page not found (404) error" when that `itemId` is wrong or if user type anything except valid id.

```
<Router>
  <div className="App">
    <Nav />
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Main} />
      <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
      <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact} />
      <Route path="/shop" exact component={Shop}>
        <Route path="/shop/:itemId" exact component={ItemDetails} />
        <Route path="*" exact component={Error404} />
      </Route>
      <Route component={Error404} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```

In above snippet everything works fine except for following part

```
<Route path="/shop" exact component={Shop}>
   <Route path="/shop/:itemId" exact component={ItemDetails} />
   <Route path="*" exact component={Error404} />
</Route>
```

Here when I go to path `/shop` or even `/shop/valid-id-OR-invalid-id` it's rendering `Error404` component only. How do I solve this issue?

P.S.: If I remove `exact` then it works fine for paths like `/contac` or `/abou` it renders `Error404` component, only if you misspell the path name. But if I try `/contact/asdasdasdd` then it renders `Contact` component. Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The thing with Router is that unless you have a Switch, it will render all routes that are prefix to the matching Route. In your case `"/shop/:itemId"` would match both `"/shop/:itemId"` and `*` and hence Error component is rendered.

Also from v4 or Router, you would need to have nested Routes within the components themselves. Also you would need to take a decision of whether itemId is valid or not within the ItemDetails component and then redirect to the 404 page if it isn't

```
<Router>
  <div className="App">
    <Nav />
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Main} />
      <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
      <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact} />
      <Route path="/shop" exact component={Shop} />
      <Route component={Error404} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```

and in Shop component you would have

```
render() {
   return (
     <div>
        {/* other elements */ }
        <Route path="/shop/:itemId" exact component={ItemDetails} />
     </div>
   )
}
```

and in ItemDetails component

```
render() {
   if(!isValid(this.props.match.params.itemId)) {
       return <Redirect to="/404" />
   }
   return (
     <>{/* ItemDetails component code */}</>
   )
}
```

Comment: Actually I can't check if itemId is valid or invalid. I was trying to say that if url didn't fetch the data then I want to display error message. I modified my question and provided with project link. Tell me if I am doing anything wrong or asked wrong question above.