# How to handle 404 in Reactjs dynamic pages based on Ajax response?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have react component with Dyanmic ID.

```
<Route path="/dashboard/tag/:id/" component={TagDetail}/>
<Route path="" component={NotFound}/>
```

In `TagDetail` Component I'm calling server for return data based on `ID`, 
But If server return `ID` is doesn't exist on server(404 status code) So I want to redirect to `NotFound` Component.

**In TagDetail Component**

```
fetch("URL", {'id": this.props.match.params.id})
     .then(response => response.json()}
     .then(data => {
           this.setState({data})
       })
```

It works when `ID` is correct so server return data but if not then can't show 404 page on that.

Comment: Why not [push](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/Navigation.md) new location to the history object you can get from [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter)?

Comment: But how can i push because NotFound Component doesn't have any path

Comment: If you push an empty string as path, it should be picked up by the router and transition to the NotFound component. Sorry for the late reply, I wasn't at computer.

Comment: Or, instead of empty string, you can also try using "/". Depends on your project.